# Pagination in Shopify Product API

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I want to fetch all products using Shopify API but unable to get it in one shot or by pagination. Also, Shopify is not allowing to do multiple requests to fetch products.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried? While you can't get all products with a single request, you can do so with "pagination" and multiply requests depending on which API are you using - GraphQL or Rest API, both of them support pagination. And Shopify allows multiply request, but you must not extend the limit set for a specific API (bucket size for GraphQL or requests per second for the Rest API) so you can't make recursive request without waiting for the previous one to finish first (overly simplified statement).

Comment: You need to take look here at how the pagination is working into Shopify admin REST API. [Link](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/make-paginated-requests-to-rest-admin-api)

Comment: We are using the same flow for Shopify API pagination in the Rest API but our question is that Shopify has recently update API rate limits (https://shopify.dev/concepts/about-apis/rate-limits) so it returns error 'Exceeded 2 calls per second for API client. Reduce request rates to resume uninterrupted service' and for this reason, we are not able to get any products.